# Compare List of characters in C#

Tags: c#, list, char, compare

I am trying to create a method to check whether a string contains same char, followring is my code:

```
public char GetCommonChar(string text)
    {
        List<char> myList = new List<char>();

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            myList.Add(text[i]);
        }

        return ' ';
    }
```

I created a list to save all characters to the list, my idea is to check whether the first index of the linst are equal with the next one, then return the character.
My question is how to compare characters in same list? Do i need another for loop that starts from index j=1 and then compare it with the previous index in the list? or is there is any other better solution?

Note: i dont want to use Linq

Comment: What you want to do compare first two character of string and if first two character is same then return that string else null ? Give example string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the list at all, you can access the characters in a string just as you would access them in a character array:

```
public char? GetCommonChar(string text) {
  for (int i = 1; i < text.Length; i++) {
    if (text[i] != text[0]) return null;
  }
  return text[0];
}
```

Note: The method returns a nullable `char`, so that it can return a `null` value if the characters differ.

#### Edit:

To find the character that occurs most often in the string you need to count how many there are of each character.

One approach is to just loop through each character and count how many there are of that character, then keep track of the character that occurs most times:

```
public char GetCommonChar(string text) {
  char result = ' ';
  int max = 0;
  foreach (char c in text) {
    int cnt = text.Count(i => i == c);
    if (cnt > max) {
      result = c;
      max = cnt;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Another approach is to have a counter for each character, then find the highest counter after counting all characters:

```
public char GetCommonChar(string text) {
  Dictionary<char, int> cnt = new Dictionary<char, int>();
  foreach (char c in text) {
    if (cnt.ContainsKey(c)) {
      cnt[c]++;
    } else {
      cnt.Add(c, 1);
    }
  }
  char result = ' ';
  int max = 0;
  foreach (KeyValuePair<char, int> item in cnt) {
    if (item.Value > max) {
      result = item.Key;
      max = item.Value;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Comment: True :), nice thought

Comment: but bro in the case where the string parameter is "AABBMGR B" for example, your code won't work..

Comment: @Kob_24: It would return `null`, as not all the characters in the string is the same. That's what I interpreted that the function was supposed to do, if you want something else then you have to explain what it is.

Comment: Yeah true,  i am just trying to make it more complicated just to learn :) thx for ur replay.. okej in this example lets say that it should return "B" the more repeated char in the string. so i have to create a counter that counts the more repeated char isn't?

Comment: @Kob_24: You need more than just a counter, you need to count how many there are of each character that occurs in the string, and find the one that occurs most times. I added two examples above.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear to me if you want to find the first occurrence of a consecutive character, ie. "l" in "hello", or first repeated character within the entire string, ie. "a" in "abca".

If first consecutive character is what you want:

```
private char? FirstConsecutiveCharacter(string input)
{
    for (var i = 1; i < input.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (input[i] == input[i - 1])
        {
            return input[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

If first repeated character within the entire string is what you want:

```
private char? FirstRepeatedCharacter(string input)
{
    var knownCharacters = new HashSet<char>();
    for (var i = 0; i < input.Length; ++i)
    {
        // Add returns true when the value is new, false when the value already exists in the hashset.
        if (!knownCharacters.Add(input[i]))
        {
            return input[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this if you want check only chars without spaces, this code return first same character where find inside string.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string text = "check this sample";

        char x = GetCommonChar(text);
        Console.WriteLine(x.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();


    }

    public static char GetCommonChar(string text)
    {
        List<char> myList = new List<char>();

        for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text[i].ToString()))
            myList.Add(text[i]);
        }

        int fpoint = 0;
        int spoint = 0;
        while (fpoint < myList.Count-1)
        {
           while (spoint < myList.Count-1)
           {
               if ((myList[fpoint] == myList[spoint + 1]) && (fpoint!=spoint+1))
                   return myList[fpoint];
               spoint++;
           }
            spoint = 0;
            fpoint++;
        }

        return ' ';

    }
```